# Conflict between AngularJS and Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, angularjs, thymeleaf

am a newbie to angularJS and Thymeleaf and am experiencing some weird conflict.

This is what I have below

```
   <input type="text" th:field="*{unit}" value="{{unit.unitID}}" class="unit_value"/>
```

Whenever the template is resolved and displayed in the browser, the value is set to empty as in something like this

```
<input class="unit_value" type="text" value="" id="unit" name="unit" />
```

am not having the angularJS expression in the value anymore.

I know the expression is synonymous to that of thymeleaf, I really dont know how to solve this.

I have searched everywhere but cant get a solution.

Comment: in angular if u want to bind that value with a scope variable ,u can make use of `ng-bind="unit.unitID"`

Comment: Are you biding a server side value (thymeleaf) or a client side value (angular)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution I found is to literally bind the tag yourself and releave thymeleaf from binding it that is just put in the expected generated html that thymeleaf will generate

```
  <input type="text" name="unit" value="{{unit.unitID}}" class="unit_value"/>
```

And everything works fine.